# Sorting an array by transpose in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

After transpose my array 'solverPacks_' i have columns for Excel.
But transpose don't sort de values in the columns from high to low...

```
var transposeToExcel = solverPacks_[0]
    .map((_, colIndex) => solverPacks_.map(row => row[colIndex])
      .join('\t')
    ).join('\n');
  console.log("transposeToExcel = " + "\n" + transposeToExcel);
```

[image]

So, can i sort the numbers from high to low in the columns during the transpose?
Will nice to have this (i show only first column) :

4298
4275
4228
4199
4189
4012
4008
3700
3659
3614
3595
3579

Thank you very much to read this!
Christina

Comment: Where is your attempt to sort the data?

Comment: Have try between the lines .sort() but with no results

Comment: You should include your attempt at sorting if you need help with sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort by column, you will have to build those columns, i.e. turn an array like `[[1,2],[3,4]]` to `[[1,3],[2,4]]`. Then you can sort it, and turn it back around again:

```js
const data = [
  [8,3,5],
  [9,2,6],
  [7,4,1]
]

const transpose = (rows) => Array.from({length: rows.length}, (_, ix) => rows.map(row => row[ix]))
const sorted = transpose(transpose(data).map(arr => arr.sort().reverse()))
console.log(sorted.map(JSON.stringify))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Moritz, this has help me out !

Comment: That's great. I really did not get a good version of `transpose()` though. Have a look at the updated answer if you are using that code. If the answer helped you out, consider giving it an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer (it is customary to do so on SO). Otherwise let me know if something is missing!